# Unable to download blob in firefox due to CSP error

Tags: javascript, firefox, blob, content-security-policy

I am trying to download a PDF file from the blob. The whole thing is in the `iframe` and when I try to download it, it throws this error in console: `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at blob:http://localhost:8080/myApp/31d389m6-8njb-n7gv-427n-bm86ynte36hc("child-src")`, I have tried this:

```
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = url;
a.download = fileName || 'download';
document.body.appendChild(a);
const clickHandler = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        this.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler);
        a.parentNode.removeChild(a);
    }, 150);
};
a.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
a.click();
```

I have added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` to both main page and as well as in the iframe, still this error is there. It is working on other browsers like chrome and edge. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Do you already have a tag like this ``<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" ...`` in your header?

Comment: @FelixSchildmann No I haven't, I only have `X-UA-Compatible` tag in both the parent page and in the iframe.

Comment: Any Content-Security-Policy header in your response headers?

Comment: @HalvorSakshaug I am not getting blob from any server, it is generated using JS only, and I am trying to download it as a file.

Answer (score 1):

Add "blob:" as "frame-src" in CSP, as per the statement "*Some browsers specifically exclude blob and filesystem from source directives.*" (reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src)

I feel firefox is one of those browsers. In my case this fixed the issue.